# transfer a copy of linux filesystem to pen drive

Tags: linux

I have a copy of Linux file system in /home/user/desktop/fs/

how tp copy it to a usb drive preserving the links

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/)

```
rsync -avPh <src> <destination>
```

alternatively you could just

```
cp -a
```

it

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the pen drive to be bootable or "LIVE" then you have a bit more work ahead of you. I suggest building a bootable USB with a tool, such as the fedora live CD/USB creator. Then put the files you want onto that live USB (rather than a blanket copy, which could be dangerous if you're overwriting system files and binaries, etc).